# Angular component bindings objects not initialised

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-components

I am using angular 1.5 components in my project . In my component i always get undefined for the object data.

I hope the $ctrl.products are not initialized before calling the product-result component. How to call the product-result component only after initializing the
$ctrl.products  objects.

products.list.component.html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-6" >
        <span>{{$ctrl.products}}</span>
        <product-result data="$ctrl.results" max="6"></product-result>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Hint: we can't see your screen.

Comment: Try removing $ sign before the variable name

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to initialized the component after initialization of $ctrl.products then you can use $compile service which angular has provided.

Use the below line just after the line where $ctrl.products is getting initialized:

```
var domObj = $compile('<my-directive></my-directive>')($scope);
$('selector where you want to append this directive').append(domObj);
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to accomplish this is to hook into angular's new component methods i.e. `$onChanges` and `$onInit`.

If `products.list.component.js` does say an API call on the products object which then renders a new `$ctrl.results` data set.

You could have `product-result.js` component check the one-way binding for `$ctrl.results` with the new `$onChanges` method.  `$onChanges` is called whenever one-way bindings are updated. The method takes in a changes object parameter.  The changes object has keys that are names of the bound properties that have changed.

Your code for `product-result.js` could be

```
/**
 * @ngdoc function
 * @name $onInit
 * @description on bootstrap for the component check if the value `ctrl.results ` is falsy    
*/
$onInit: function $onInit () {
    if (!this.results) {
        this.showNoDataAvaliable = true;
    }
},

/**
 * @ngdoc function
 * @name $onChanges
 * @description when component product-list passes a new value for $ctrl.results,  Show the data.
 * @param {Object} changes the changes object when any binding property is updated, this is similar to
 * having a watch function on $scope.variable   
 */
$onChanges: function $onChanges (changes) {
    if (changes.data && changes.data.currentValue) {
        this.showNoDataAvaliable = false;
        //... more code on how to display the data.
    }
}
```

Todd Motto has a great blog post about angular 1.5 component, I recommend you read
https://toddmotto.com/angular-1-5-lifecycle-hooks

Answer (score 2):

A much more simple solution is just to use ng-if to delay the rendering of the inner component until the results are loaded:

```
<product-result ng-if="$ctrl.results" data="$ctrl.results" max="6"></product-result>
```

This will allow you to keep your HTML in the template where it belongs but will prevent the inner component from being added to the DOM and initialized until `$ctrl.results` is defined.